# Volume of balls in homogeneous manifolds

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $X=G/H$ be a homogeneous manifold, where $G$ and $H$ are connected Lie groups and assume there is given a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $X$.
Let $B(R)$ be the closed ball of radius $R>0$ around the base point $eH$  and let $b(R)$ denote its volume.
Is it rue that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\ \limsup_{R\to\infty}\ \frac{b(R+\varepsilon)}{b(R)}=1?\qquad(\#)
$$
The idea somehow being that volume growth is largest with constant negative curvature in which case it is exponential and thus satisfies our claim.

Comment: I think it's known (to be checked, since these kind of statements have several variants, the first being maybe due to Pansu) that in case $G$ (and hence $X$) has polynomial growth, then for some $d$, $b(R)/R^d$ has a limit in $]0,\infty[$. In this case we already have $\lim b(R+\varepsilon)/b(R)=1$ for each fixed $\varepsilon$, which is not a formal consequence of having polynomially bounded growth.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a connected Riemannian manifold with bounded sectional curvature, for which the convergence ($\#$) fails?

Comment: Probably not. But I didn't want to be too daring.

Comment: What if $X$ is compact - say, a sphere? You obviously need some more conditions (e.g.  negative curvature) for the question to make sense.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov If $X$ is compact, then $b(R)=vol(X)$ for $R$ large enough, so the limsup is already $1$ for fixed $\varepsilon$. This is not the interesting case but I don't see a problem here.

Comment: It's rather that the existence of a counterexample without homogeneity property is a natural motivation for the question.

Comment: @YCor: My answer shows that all you need is Ricci curvature bounded below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The idea somehow being that volume growth is largest with constant negative curvature

is essentially the content of the Bishop–Cheeger–Gromov comparison theorem.  See for instance Lemma 36 of Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry*, 2ed.  It states, in his notation, that in any complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of dimension $n$ with Ricci curvature bounded below by $(n-1)k$, the function
$$r \mapsto \frac{\operatorname{vol} B(p,r)}{v(n,k,r)}$$
is nonincreasing, where $B(p,r)$ is the ball in $(M,g)$ centered at $p$ with radius $r$, and $v(n,k,r)$ is the volume of the ball of radius $r$ in the space form of dimension $n$ and constant sectional curvature $k$.  A homogeneous space certainly has bounded Ricci curvature, and the interesting case for us is when $k$ is negative, so that $v(n,k,r)$ is the volume in hyperbolic space, which as you say grows exponentially.

So this result tells us that
$$\frac{\operatorname{vol} B(p,r)}{v(n,k,r)} \ge \frac{\operatorname{vol} B(p,r+\epsilon)}{v(n,k,r+\epsilon)}$$
or in other words
$$1 \le \frac{\operatorname{vol} B(p,r+\epsilon)}{\operatorname{vol} B(p,r)} \le \frac{v(n,k,r+\epsilon)}{v(n,k,r)}.$$
As $r \to \infty$ the right side converges to something of the form $e^{c \epsilon}$, which in turn goes to $1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Concerning your last statement, and related to it: how does the area of metric spheres grow in a complete manifold with bounded (in my case constant) curvature? Is it guaranteed to be at most exponential? Could you please give a reference?

Comment: A reference for the growth of the volume would be equally good, of course, if you know any. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexM.: Yes, it is at most exponential.  In a space of constant negative curvature, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3652822/822) for the volume, which you can easily check is a function that grows exponentially.